# NestJS unit test with jest with two mongoose ObjectID

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

Give below is a function in a NestJS service class, for which I want to write some unit tests.

```
async create(
    counselorId: string,
    createLocationReservationDto: CreateLocationReservationDto,
): Promise<LocationReservation> {
    // checking the provided ID is a valid ObjectId
    const isValidCounselorId = mongoose.isValidObjectId(counselorId);
    if (!isValidCounselorId)
        throw new BadRequestException(`Counselor #${counselorId} is not valid.`);

    const counselor = await this.counselorModel.findById(counselorId);
    if (!counselor)
        throw new NotFoundException(`Counselor #${counselorId} not found`);

    // checking the provided ID is a valid ObjectId
    const isValidLocationId = mongoose.isValidObjectId(
        createLocationReservationDto.location,
    );
    if (!isValidLocationId)
        throw new BadRequestException(
            `Location #${createLocationReservationDto.location} is not valid.`,
        );

    const location = await this.locationModel.findById(
        createLocationReservationDto.location,
    );
    if (!location)
        throw new NotFoundException(
            `Location #${createLocationReservationDto.location} not found`,
        );

    const locationReservation = await this.locationReservationModel.create({
        ownedBy: counselorId,
        ...createLocationReservationDto,
    });

    return locationReservation;
}
```

Given below is my attempt at writing a unit test in `Jest` for the above NestJS service function.

```
it('should throw BadRequestException if invalid ID is given', async () => {
    const newCounselorLocationReservationDto = {
        startDate: '24-11-2023',
        endDate: '24-12-2023',
        startTime: 3333,
        endTime: 5555,
        location: 'invalid-id',
    };

    jest.spyOn(counselorModel, 'findById').mockResolvedValue(true);
    await counselorModel.findById(mockLocationReservation.ownedBy)

    const isValidCounselorObjectIdMock = jest
        .spyOn(mongoose, 'isValidObjectId')
        .mockReturnValue(true);
    const isValidLocationObjectIdMock = jest
        .spyOn(mongoose, 'isValidObjectId')
        .mockReturnValue(false);

    await expect(
        locationReservationService.create(
            mockLocationReservation.ownedBy, // mockLocationReservation.ownedBy = '64db4fed192a47efa0ea9838'
            newCounselorLocationReservationDto as CreateLocationReservationDto,
        ),
    ).rejects.toThrow(BadRequestException);

    // restoring the original behavior of isValidObjectId after the test
    isValidCounselorObjectIdMock.mockRestore();
    isValidLocationObjectIdMock.mockRestore();
});
```

This is just one test case in my test suite, where I pass a valid counselor ID and invalid location ID.

When I try to run the tests, it's not working.